# Purpose of 中 in 自然の中で

Tags: grammar, particle-で, relational-nouns

> 自然**の中で**ゆっくり凍った氷の味を楽しんでください。
>   Please enjoy the flavour of ice slowly made by nature.

If not sure if I should read this as 'ice made **by** nature' or 'ice made **in** nature'. The 中 is really confusing me because I normally think of this as inside/among/throughout, none of which really seem to work well here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Japanese verb for 'made' does not appear in your sentence. The word frozen is (凍｛こお｝る）.

What does 中 mean? Inside/within. What does 中で mean? Occurring inside/within.

自然 and its English counterpart 'nature' can refer to 'a natural environment'.

自然の中 = in nature, 自然の中で = occurring within nature (natural surroundings)

自然の中で凍った = Frozen within natural surroundings (a natural environment).